# need a tool to replace a string in multiple files by another string

Tags: php, unix

I have been looking around and I find grep and Gawk fairly difficult to grasp without much knowledge on UNIX. I have about 50 php files and I need to replace "stringA" inside each of these files by "stringB" Does someone know of an easy to use tool? If I had extra time I could write one up in PHP with the search functions.

Comment: Sed is fairly advanced, I believe there are text editors out there that will let you open a bunch of files at once and do a find/replace with the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can open multiple files with ultra edit and do a find replace all on them. 
http://www.ultraedit.com/

Comment: While "workable", I think shell proficiency is very important for anyone developing on UNIX. Shell pipelines are more reliable, more flexible, lighter and can work even when you don't have X running.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are all in the same folder:

```
sed -i 's/stringA/stringB/g' *.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/stringA/stringB/g' *
```

Be careful though

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl

```
noufal@sanitarium% cat tmp
StringA
Test nameStringB
Testing StringA
StringC

noufal@sanitarium% perl -e s/StringA/StringB/g -pi tmp 
noufal@sanitarium% more tmp
StringB
Test nameStringB
Testing StringB
StringC
```

You can pass multiple files to the command.